# Reduce image opacity but not the background color of button

Tags: html, css

I have written below CSS for button to show image and color both in button but I want to reduce opacity of image not the color but if I tried to apply opacity to button it reduce both how can I achieve that I can reduce opacity of button image not its color opacity below is my code

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0F69AF;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: url("../Images/Test.png");
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.button span {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font: 18px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column1" style="width:60%">
  <button class="button"><a href="../test" target="_blank"><span>Test1222</span> </a></button>
  <br><button class="button"><a href="../test" target="_blank"><span>TEST123</span> </a></button>
</div>
```

Comment: There’s no CSS property that you can use to change the opacity of only the background image. You need an actual image - or a (pseudo) element that only serves as a container for the image, to apply opacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no CSS property that you can use to change the opacity of only the background image. You need an actual image - or a (pseudo) element that only serves as a container for the image, to apply opacity.

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0F69AF;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* needs to be positioned */
  position: relative;
}

.button::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url("//placekitten.com/400/100");
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
  content: '';
}

.button span {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font: 18px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column1" style="width:60%">
  <button class="button"><a href="../test" target="_blank"><span>Test1222</span> </a></button>
  <br><button class="button"><a href="../test" target="_blank"><span>TEST123</span> </a></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-blend-mode: lighten;` or other values such as screen or overlay. It is important to have the (background color+image) or two different images as background for the effect.

Comment: That won't allow fine-grained control over the amount of opacity, though. If that is not required, your approach is preferrable.

Comment: Very true, but I thought only effect was important not the opacity control. Your answer covers the exact application as it should be. Kudos!